# Java web - sessions design for horizontal scalability

Tags: java, database, session, architecture

I'm definitely not an expert Java coder, I need to implement sessions in my java Servlet based web application, and as far as I know this is normally done through HttpSession. However this method stores the session data in the local filesystem and I don't want to have such constraints to horizontal scalability. Therefore I thought to save sessions in an external database to which the application communicates through a REST interface. 
Basically in my application there are users performing some actions such as searches. Therefore what I'm going to persist in sessions is essentialy the login data, and the meta data associated to searches.

As the main data storage I'm planning to use a graph noSQL database, the question is: let's say I can eventually also use another database of another kind for sessions, which architecture fits better for this kind of situation?

I currently thought to two possible ways. the first one uses another db (such as an SQL db) to store sessions data. In this way I would have a more distributed workload since I'm not using the main storage also for sessions. Moreover I'd also have a more organized environment being session state variables and persisten ones not mixed up.
The second way instead consists in storing every information relative to any session into the "user node" of the main database. The sessionid will be at this point just a "shortcut" for an authentication. This way I dont have to rely on a second database, however I move all the workload to the main db mixing the session data with the persistent ones.

is there any standard general architecture to which I can ake reference? DO I miss some important point which should constraint my architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to store sessions in a different location is good. How about using an in-memory cache like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [redis](http://redis.io/)? Session data is generally not long-lived so you have other options other than a full-blown database. Memcached & Redis can both be clustered and can scale horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, of course a cache layer will be present. However I'd like to have the full guarantee that an user will never experience a session-miss. Moreover since my main client will be a mobile app, I also would like to limit the login procedure as much as possible, and the idea were simply to use a sessionid to recover a login any time one wants. This however would not work with a non-persistent session.

Comment: the cache would support that use case. clustering it can ensure high availability

Comment: Yes, thanks. Maybe a good solution might be. store the sessionid (or whatever I'll use for the login-shortcut) into the main db and use the memcache to store searches and other "more short term" data, isn't it? The only doubts I had on memcache are  
a) I have limits in the cache use related to its cost since for now I'm relying on a PaaS. (So I have concurrency\space limits). However a database is not actually much better.  
b) I wanted to use the memcache also for the main dataabse entries and this will lead to higher cache-miss rate also for sessions.

Comment: you would store the object in the cache and look them up by sessionid. using memcached for data that is meant to be permanently persisted may not be the best idea.

Comment: yes, sure my key will be the sessionid. for the main permanent data why you say its not the best?

Comment: well, there are tradeoffs - it really depends on your requirements and whether you would want strong transactional guarantees for non-session data.